# Match specific string which not contains specific pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have urls and want to match only those which match this pattern

```sh
^/zxp/companies/.*?/queries/.*?$
```

but not contains this `type=inbox` - so for example - regexp should give following results:

```
"/zxp/companies/432523/queries/4344?read=2&type=inbox"   -> FALSE
"/zxp/companies/432523/queries/4344?type=inbox&read=2"   -> FALSE
"/zxp/companies/432523/queries/4344?type=query&read=2"   -> TRUE
"/zxp/companies/432523/queries/4344"                     -> TRUE
"/zxp/companies/432523/buildings/4344?type=query&read=2" -> FALSE
"/zxp/companies/432523/buildings/4344"                   -> FALSE
```

I try this but get wrong results (good only when type=inbox is at the end of string)

```js
let re = /^\/zxp\/companies\/.+?\/queries\/.*(?<!type=inbox)$/

let tests = [
  "/zxp/companies/432523/queries/4344?read=2&type=inbox",
  "/zxp/companies/432523/queries/4344?type=inbox&read=2",
  "/zxp/companies/432523/queries/4344?type=query&read=2",
  "/zxp/companies/432523/queries/4344",
  "/zxp/companies/432523/buildings/4344?type=query&read=2",
  "/zxp/companies/432523/buildings/4344",
]



tests.forEach(t => console.log(`${t} -> ${re.test(t)}`))
```

How to do it using JavaScript RegExp?

Comment: Perhaps something like `^\/zxp\/companies\/\d+\/queries\/\d+\b(?!.*\btype=inbox\b).*$` https://regex101.com/r/x4Bewe/1 or `^\/zxp\/companies\/.+?\/queries\/(?!.*\btype=inbox\b).*$`  https://regex101.com/r/IwTZE8/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird - it looks correct -  please write your comment as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern that you tried asserts that the string does not end with `type=inbox` using `(?<!type=inbox)$` which is a negative lookbehind.

You can use a negative lookahead instead, adding it after `/queries/`, to assert that from that position `type=inbox` does not occur at the right.

**Note** that it would also match `/zxp/companies/432523/queries/`

```
^\/zxp\/companies\/.+?\/queries\/(?!.*\btype=inbox\b).*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/afra4C/1)

A bit more specific variant of the pattern could be

```
^\/zxp\/companies\/\d+\/queries\/\d+\b(?!.*\btype=inbox\b).*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x4Bewe/1)

```js
let re = /^\/zxp\/companies\/.+?\/queries\/(?!.*type=inbox).*$/

let tests = [
  "/zxp/companies/432523/queries/4344?read=2&type=inbox",
  "/zxp/companies/432523/queries/4344?type=inbox&read=2",
  "/zxp/companies/432523/queries/4344?type=query&read=2",
  "/zxp/companies/432523/queries/4344",
  "/zxp/companies/432523/buildings/4344?type=query&read=2",
  "/zxp/companies/432523/buildings/4344",
]



tests.forEach(t => console.log(`${t} -> ${re.test(t)}`))
```

---

As there is [more support](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) in Javascript to use a lookbehind, another option could be a variant of the pattern that you tried, asserting that the part after the last `/` does not contain type=inbox.

```
^\/zxp\/companies\/.+?\/queries\/.*(?<!\btype=inbox\b[^\r\n/]*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1oJv3q/1)

Comment: it looks like when we remove `\b` for your regexp it also works - do you know why?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Yes it also works, but then it would also not match for longer words as `\b` is a word boundary. See https://regex101.com/r/I7CpF8/1 vs https://regex101.com/r/wl9VAe/1

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
^\/zxp\/companies\/.*?\/queries\/(?!.*?type=inbox).*?$
```

I hope that this will be useful for you.

[image]

I recomend to you this page to do regex test:
https://regexr.com/

[image]

For these case select in the "Flags" option and choose "Global" for multiple matches and "MultiLine" for match "^$" in multiple lines

Answer (score 0):

```
let checkIfType = /type=inbox/;
myString = 'checkmystringtype=inbox';
if(!checkIfType.test(myString)){
  //code here will work if there is no 'type=inbox' inside string
}
```